# Read one text file line by line, for each line, substitute another text file with all the uppercase string of the line just read

Tags: bash, awk, sed

e.g.
Read f1.txt line by line, for each line L, substitute f2.txt with all the uppercase string of L.

f1.txt

```
sone
stwo
```

f2.txt

```
st
 sone
  stwo
so
```

desired output:

```
st
 SONE
  STWO
so
```

I tried:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\U\1/' f2.txt
done < f1.txt
```

Comment: If `f2.txt` contains the line `prisoner`, what should the corresponding output line be?

Comment: do both files consist solely of a single string (with no embedded white space) per line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible interpretation of your requirements, using any awk and reading all of `f1.txt` into memory but only reading 1 line at a time of `f2.txt` into memory:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} {for (re in a) gsub(re,toupper(re))} 1' f1.txt f2.txt
st
 SONE
  STWO
so
```

Regarding the attempt in your question, the syntax for that approach would be this, using GNU sed for `-i` (which I think you need for `\U` anyway):

```
tmp=$(mktemp) &&
cp -- f2.txt "$tmp" &&
while read -r line; do
  sed -i 's/'"$line"'/\U&/' "$tmp"
done < f1.txt &&
cat "$tmp"
rm -f "$tmp"
```

but please read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for some of the reasons not to do that.

Comment: `sed 's|.*|s/&/\\U\&/|' f1.txt | sed -f - f2.txt > new_f2.txt`. Note that like the awk, this treats lhs as a regex. unlike the awk, it will change meaning (or break) if characters such as `/`, `[` or `\ ` appear

Comment: @jhnc I know there's other ways to do it, I was just showing the OP the correct syntax for the shell loop calling sed code they had tried to write (but shouldn't write).

Answer (score 3):

Assumptions:

- all lines (both files) consist of a single string (no embedded white space)

Another `awk` approach:

```
awk '
FNR==NR { a[$1]; next }
$1 in a { $0=toupper($0) }
1
' f1.txt f2.txt

#### or as a one-liner:

awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1]; next } $1 in a { $0=toupper($0) } 1' f1.txt f2.txt
```

This generates:

```
st
 SONE
  STWO
so
```

Answer (score 2):

With bash >4.3:

```
# load strings into an array
mapfile -t a <f1.txt

# load file as a string (single array element)
mapfile -d '' b <f2.txt

# do substitutions
for s in "${a[@]}"; do b=${b//"$s"/"${s^^}"}; done

# output the result
printf '%s' "$b" >new_f2.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU AWK

```
$ awk '
       NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} 
       gensub(/\s*/,"",1,$0) in a{$0 = toupper($0)}
1' f1.txt f2.txt
st
 SONE
  STWO
so
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers!
I learned a lot!
@ Ed Morton, thank you for providing both awk and sed solutions!
After seeing the awk one-liner solution, I will avoid using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE '1{x;s/^/cat file2/e;x};G;s/^([^\n]+).*\n\s*(\1)(\n.*|$)/\U\1/;P' file1
```

Turn off implicit printing and on extended regexps.

On the first line, slurp in file2 to the hold space.

For each line, append the hold space, using pattern matching uppercase the first word if that word is duplicated and print only the first line.